# Can I customize the Release action in Cash Sales?

Tags: acumatica

I need to change how a Release procedure works. Specifically, I need to change the Release button on the Cash Sales site to use custom fields to populate the Cash Account and Subaccount fields. I found that the release button forwards the process to  `ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc()` which is located in `PX.Objects.AR`. This led me to believe that I need to customize the function that exists in 'PX.Objects.AR', but I'm not sure if that is doable.

Is it possible to customize functions that exist in the PX.Objects DLL? If not, is it possible for me to force the function in the DLL to receive custom fields for the Cash Account and Subaccount values instead of the base fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ARDocumentRelease` is the process list page which calls `ARReleaseProcess` for each document release and is a graph. You can create a graph extension to override the calls it makes which is a virtual call to ReleaseDocProc meaning you can use `PXOverride` in your graph extension to override the call. Without testing, it could look something like this...

```
public class ARReleaseProcessExtension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AR.ARReleaseProcess>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual List<PX.Objects.AR.ARRegister> ReleaseDocProc(PX.Objects.GL.JournalEntry je, PX.Objects.AR.ARRegister ardoc, List<PX.Objects.GL.Batch> pmBatchList,
        PX.Objects.AR.ARDocumentRelease.ARMassProcessReleaseTransactionScopeDelegate onreleasecomplete, 
        Func<PX.Objects.GL.JournalEntry, PX.Objects.AR.ARRegister, List<PX.Objects.GL.Batch>, PX.Objects.AR.ARDocumentRelease.ARMassProcessReleaseTransactionScopeDelegate, List<PX.Objects.AR.ARRegister>> del)
    {
        //Code before...

        //The base call...
        var ret = del?.Invoke(je, ardoc, pmBatchList, onreleasecomplete);

        //Code after...

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh ha, I'll give this a try. Does every graph have a ReleaseProcess graph?

Comment: most of the major modules such as AR, AP, IN, etc. have a document release process. The release process will most likely process all types of documents so just make sure you are working with the type of doc you need (I have not worked with AR and AP docs to know the different just assume there are differences and different doc types)